# Rails 4 nested form data not being saved, has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I'm trying to make an app that allows people to submit info to one model, while also filling in some data about it from another model. Currently the form works, but the data for the nested form isn't saving

Here's my controller

```
class Requests::AgesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @age = Age.new
        @industries = Industry.all.map{ |i| [i.name, i.id ]}
        @age.ages_industries.build
    end

    def create
    @age = Age.new(age_params)

    if @age.save
      flash[:success] = "Age #{@age.name} has been created!"
      redirect_to admin_ages_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Sorry! We were unable to create that age."
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private

  def age_params
    params.require(:age)\
          .permit(:name,
                  :about_title,
                  :about_body,
                  :url,
                  :email,
                  :phone,
                  :street,
                  :city,
                  :state,
                  :zip,
                  :country,
                  :is_published,
                  age_industries_attributes: [:age_id, :industry_id])
  end           
end
```

relevant bits of the age model

```
has_many :ages_industries,
    dependent: :delete_all
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ages_industries


has_many :industries,
    :through => :ages_industries,
    :uniq => true
```

ages_industries model

```
class AgesIndustry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :age, touch: true
    belongs_to :industry
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :industry
    self.primary_key = :id
end
```

relevant bits of the industry model

```
has_many :ages_industries
has_many :ages,
   :through => :ages_industries,
   :uniq => true
```

form

```
section#main
    .wrapper
        h1 Add an Age
        = simple_form_for [:requests, @age] do |form|
            .formElem.m20t.m20b
              = form.error_notification
            .formElem.m20b
              = form.input :name
            .formElem.m20b
              = form.simple_fields_for :ages_industries do |builder|
                    = builder.input :industry_id, collection: @industries, :value => params[:id]
            .fix
            .formElem.m20b
              = form.input :about_title
            .formElem.m20b
              = form.input :about_body
            .formElem.m20b
              = form.input :url
            .formElem.m20b
              = form.input :email
            .formElem.m20b
              = form.input :phone
            .formElem.m20b
              = form.input :street
            .formElem.m20b
              = form.input :city
            .formElem.m20b
              = form.input :state
            .formElem.m20b
              = form.input :zip
            .formElem.m20b.m20t
              = form.input :country, collection: Carmen::country_names
            .fix
            .formElem.m20b
              = form.input :is_published
            .formElem.m20b.m20t
              = form.button :submit, class: "formBtn"
              |  or 
              = link_to "cancel", admin_ages_path
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the form?

Comment: Is this a typo? `params.require(:age)\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, you're missing a pluralization when you permit the nested params. i.e. ages instead of age.

```
params.require(:age).permit(ages_industries_attributes: [...])
```

If that doesn't fix it, I would put a `pry` or a `byebug` in your controller create action and check out the contents of `params` and `age_params` to make sure they are aligned.